# Problems with interrupt arduino nano with NRF24le1

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I am trying to build a wireless control of an LED Stripe.

For this I use 2 Arduino Nano's with a NRF24le1 chip to communicate with each other.

Arduino 1 serves as a controller / master and has 3 buttons and 1 fader for the choice of the respective light mode / blackout, as well as the to serve light intensity.

I would like the values ​​as 6 bytes (button1, button2, button3,
faderintensiät) and received on the 2nd Arduino.

Not constant values ​​are sent, only at change of values.

On the 2nd Nano should then be activated by interrupt flags, if an button press what and the current value from Fader Held so that the loop stays clear and there via the RGBW Led Stripe, ever after which flag is selected, can be iterated.

How can I attach the interrupt? On my Transmitter Adruino the stream is running

This is my code:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
#include <avr/power.h> // Required for 16 MHz Adafruit Trinket
#endif

#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

#define LED_PIN 3
#define LED_COUNT 228

uint8_t BRIGHTNESS = 60;

// Declare our NeoPixel strip object:
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, NEO_GRBW + NEO_KHZ800);

RF24 wirelessSPI(7, 8); // CE, CSN

#define PinIRQ 3  // Arduino Uno, Mega und Nano: Pin 3
#define IRQ 1

const byte address[6] = "00001";


boolean light_on = false;
boolean mode_a_active = false;
boolean mode_b_active = false;

boolean receivedMessage = false;
int interruptcounter = 0;


uint8_t settings[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};                 //Saving the incoming data

void setup() {
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  wirelessSPI.begin();
  //wirelessSPI.setAutoAck(1);                  //new
  //wirelessSPI.enableAckPayload();              //new
  //wirelessSPI.maskIRQ(1,1,0);                 //new
  wirelessSPI.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);       //You can set this as minimum or maximum depending on the distance between the transmitter and receiver.
  wirelessSPI.openReadingPipe(0, address);   //Setting the address at which we will receive the data
  wirelessSPI.startListening();              //This sets the module as receiver

  strip.begin();           // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip object (REQUIRED)
  strip.show();            // Turn OFF all pixels ASAP
  strip.setBrightness(50); // Set BRIGHTNESS to about 1/5 (max = 255)

  attachInterrupt(IRQ, incomingmessage, HIGH);
}

void loop()
{
  wirelessSPI.read(&settings, sizeof(settings));  //Reading the data

  if(receivedMessage == true){
    Serial.println("messange on interupt received");
    Serial.print("interruptcounter counts: ");
    Serial.println(interruptcounter);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(settings[0]);
    Serial.print(settings[1]);
    Serial.print(settings[2]);
    Serial.print(settings[3]);
    Serial.print(settings[4]);
    Serial.println(settings[5]);
    receivedMessage = false;
  }
}

void incomingmessage()
{
  interruptcounter++;
  while (wirelessSPI.available()) {
    wirelessSPI.read(&settings, sizeof(settings));  //Reading the data
    receivedMessage = true;    // Variable setzen, dass eine neue Nachricht zur Auswertung bereit steht
  }
}
```